# Iterative regex capturing in C#

Tags: c#, regex, recursion, capturing-group

I have to read in a file that contains a number of coordinates. The file is structured in the following way:

```
X1/Y1,X2/Y2,X3/Y3,X4/Y4
```

Where X and Y are positive integers. To solve this problem I want to use a regex (I think this is in general a good idea because of minimal refactoring when the pattern changes).

Therefore I have developed the following regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@^(?<Coor>(?<X>[0-9]+)/(?<Y>[0-9]+))(,(?<Coor>(?<X>[0-9]+)/(?<Y>[0-9]+)))*$");
```

However when I test this regex on data, for example:

```
1302/1425,1917/2010
```

The Regex only seems to recall the last X, Y and Coor group. In this case Coor is "12/17", X is "1917" and Y is "2010". Is there a way to generate some sort of tree. So I find an object who gives me all the Coor expressions, with under each Coor an X and Y component?

If possible, I would like to use only one Regex, this because the format could perhaps change to another one.

Comment: EDIT: I also need to validate the Regex, using Regex.Matches doesn't validate the string.

Comment: Do you know what kind of change that is expected in the format?

Comment: There is nothing recursive about this. You probably mean iterative.

Comment: @CommuSoft: It would be simpler to do the validation separately from extracting the values instead of trying to do both at once. Could you do that?

Comment: I think indeed I could first validate the complete Regex, and then use the Matches method to extract the data from every piece. However I am also intrested in a general method for problems like this. What for instance if the comma would (I think it will not) be replaced by a more complex structure so false matches can be captured. Is there a general way to build a tree like this.

Comment: @Guffa: anything that can be solved iteratively can also be solved recursively. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can quite easily solve this without any regular expression by using `string.Split` and `int.Parse`:

```
var coords = s.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Split('/'))
    .Select(a => new {
        X = int.Parse(a[0]),
        Y = int.Parse(a[1])
    });
```

If you want to use a regular expression to *validate* the string you could do it like this:

```
"^(?!,)(?:(?:^|,)[0-9]+/[0-9]+)*$"
```

If you want to use a regular expression based approach also for *extracting the data* you could first validate the string using the above regular expression and then extra the data as follows:

```
var coords = Regex.Matches(s, "([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => new
    {
        X = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value),
        Y = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value)
    });
```

If you really want to perform the validation and data extraction simultaneously with a single regular expression you can use two capturing groups and find the results in the `Captures` property for each group. Here's one way you could perform both the validation and data extraction using a single regular expression:

```
List<Group> groups =
    Regex.Matches(s, "^(?!,)(?:(?:^|,)([0-9]+)/([0-9]+))*$")
         .Cast<Match>().First()
         .Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1)
         .ToList();

var coords = Enumerable.Range(0, groups[0].Captures.Count)
    .Select(i => new
    {
        X = int.Parse(groups[0].Captures[i]),
        Y = int.Parse(groups[1].Captures[i])
    });
```

However you may want to consider whether the complexity of this solution is worth it compared to the `string.Split` based solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to use a regular expression for such a simple format.

Just split the string and use plain string operations to get the coordinates:

```
var coordinates =
  fileContent.Split(',').Select(s => {
    int pos = s.IndexOf("/");
    return new {
      X = s.Substring(0, pos),
      Y = s.Substring(pos + 1)
    };
  });
```

If the file format gets much more complicated you can refactor it into using a regular expression. Until then, simple code like this is much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You might get what you seek if you use the "Matches" rather than "Match" command.  Also, can't you shorten the regex perhaps to this:

```
Regex(@"((?<Coor>(?<X>[0-9]+)/(?<Y>[0-9]+))|,)*");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your first problem is that your regex is flawed, the anchors are throwing off the matching.  This is the one I came up with: (just the regex shown here, no code)

`(?<Coor>(?<X>[0-9]+)/(?<Y>[0-9]+))`

The one Mystagogue works as well, but produces 'blank' matches on the commas (for me).